# Error while attempting to connect to an Oracle 12c database using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle12c

I am trying to connect to an oracle 12c database using the eclipse IDE but I get the error "Ping Failed!" every time I try to test the connection. I have tried to  disable the windows firewall as some other similar post suggested it might be network related or the fire wall blocking it. I have the following settings:
SID: XE
Host: localhost
Port Number: 1521
UserName: myusername
Password: mypassword
connection URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.oracle.JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: server
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:120)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 18 more
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "server" is not a known host.

Comment: any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection url to `jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:db`. This will work.